# この  は何ですか？ 普通の C と何が異なるのですか？

Tags: 文字コード

この  は何ですか？ 普通の C と何が異なるのですか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> この  は何ですか？

Unicodeの数学用英数字記号です。

> 普通の C と何が異なるのですか？

と `C` は別の文字です。`C` はASCIIに含まれていますが、 は含まれていません。

: [U+1D63E](https://codepoints.net/U+1D63E?lang=en)
C: [U+0043](https://codepoints.net/U+0043?lang=en)

Comment: "Mathematical Sans-Serif Bold Italic Capital C"(数学用のSans-Serif体の太字、イタリック(斜体字)の大文字のc)と説明されています。